# Calling GUITest from APITest in HP-UFT

Tags: web-services, qtp, hp-uft

We have scenario like passing soap request with session ID which can be generated by another IE session.

Every time we create new session ID manually from that IE session and feed it in SOAP request and invoke the service.

Recently we started using HP-UFT for API and GUI testing.

I was able to create a script to generate SessionID using GUI Test and Run the service request using API Test.

Both are in same solution explorer only.

But I can't find the way to invoke / call GUI Test from API test in HP-UFT, In order to get values of session ID.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call GUI test from API just by dragging GUI test into Test Flow. 
here is how :

Assuming you already created API test and included your Soap request in Test Flow:

Go to Menu --->View--->Toolbox (if you don't see toolbox on the left side),

from the all available options --Select (HP Automated Testing Tool)---Drag (Call GUI Action or test) into test flow right before your Soap Request.

Now on the left side you will see GUI test property , select the GUI test you wanna run (Remember make it return your Session ID as output parameter)

At this point , all you need to do is Link output parameter of GUI Test with Input Parameter of Soap Request,Then run the test .

Please let me know if you need any additional help

Comment: Thanks Aragon, I was able to make guitest and apitest in same Test Flow. But I can't link output parameter [session id] of GuiTest to Apitest, session ID allows only link to Data Source; not parameters in Apitest properties. Please let me know if any other work around.

Comment: Thanks for selecting my answer , Here is the answer for your question :

Answer (score 0):

In GUI Test, when you click on the action in canvas, you will see property of the action and also parameter section, which we call the action parameter.

- Add an output parameter called `SessionID` in your case
- At the end of your test you will make your SessionID assign to `Parameter("SessionID")`
- Go to your API test, link your Target field with the output parameter of GUI test just like you link API test field with each other
- Make sure it's the output parameter of the GUI, because that's the only thing you can access from later actions in Canvas.